# Vue.js Form submits immediately shown with v-if

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, webpack

Am building a *Wordpress* plugin and am Using Vue Js. 
I set up a variable that will be set to true on a button click
Then another div which is a modal that will remaining hidden with v-if as long as the variable is false. The is also a form in the div modal(pop up)

The problem is that once the value changes, on button pressed, the form submits immediately.

This has been happening but I usually ignore it because there was always a required field which will prevent the form from submitting automatically.

Vue.js Data object

```
{
  selected_to_show : false,
}
```

The modal div

```
<div v-if="selected_to_show === true" class='mp-modal'>

  <form on:submit.prevent="xhrSubmit()">

  <form>
</div>

<button v-on:click="selected_to_show = true"></button>
```

This works but once the modal opens, the form submits immediately.

Note: There is only two button elements in the form where are all set to type="button"

The target is to prevent the form from submitting automatically when shown

Comment: There are two mistakes in the code provided. The closing `<form>` tag is missing a slash and the `submit` listener needs to be `v-on:` rather than `on:`. However, neither of these explains why the form is submitting. My guess would be that you've got code to submit the form that is running prematurely but you haven't included that code so it's difficult to know exactly. e.g. Could be a `v-on` that's incorrectly been written as a `v-bind`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one still uses this approach to re-render vue apps, my advice is, don't.

The best way to re-render the app is by doing

```
this.forceUpdate();
```

This will re-render the vue app instead of modifying data properties of the vue instance which are utilized during rendering.

However, don't overuse it.
Most times when your view is not re-rendering naturally, its probably because you are doing something wrong.